# How to retrieve file path of `spring.config.location` argument in Spring Boot 2.3?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When using Spring Boot 2.3 I can provide `application.yaml` file as an external file via `--spring.config.location=/path/to/application.yaml`.
All properties can be retrieved from that file but I need to retrieve a file path of `application.yaml`.
Sometimes I can find this file path in `AbstractEnvironment` inside one of PropertySources (`environment.getPropertySources()`) with the key `--spring.config.location` but that not always the case. For example, when I am running the application via docker:

```
CMD ["java", "-jar", "myApp.jar", "--spring.config.location=/path/to/application.yaml"]
```

Properties from `/path/to/application.yaml` are used but I cannot find `--spring.config.location` in the resulting properties.

Comment: Why do you need this path?

Comment: To parse yaml file which is provided via `spring.config.location` using `SnakeYAML` and retrieve part of a yaml configuration in `yaml` format to supply 3rd party library with the InputStream which contains part of yaml configuration. I don't know exact properties which will be used in `spring.config.location` file because it depends on what 3rd party library accepts. Additional explanation / question on the format can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62799350/how-to-retrieve-a-part-of-yaml-configuration-file-in-spring-boot-2-3

Comment: The idea is to have a single configuration file which configures spring boot application and all dependent libraries instead of using multiple configuration files.

Comment: Then I would strongly suggest to use seperate well known config files as afaik there is no standard way of getting that property as it might be the default location or a provided location or it might even be a collection of files. If the `spring.config.location` is a directory it will load multiple files and not a single one. So even if you could it would be a brittle solution.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion! Makes sense.